# Encrypt Odoo Attachments and send by email

Tags: python, encryption, odoo, odoo-13

I have a problem where when sending a payslip, the system should retrieve the generated payslip, encrypt it and then send it via email as an encrypted attachment.

The problem is that when I save the pdf, it outputs either a blank file or a non-readable file throwing an error `File type unknown (application/octet-stream) is not supported`.

I have confirmed that the variable `pdf[0] is actually a pdf in bytes format.

So my question is how to save this pdf data into a human readable pdf file.

So this is my python code.
This method will call an odoo send-email popup with the pdf attached.

The `save_pdf_file()` function just takes the path and saves the encrypted attachment back to odoo so that it can be attached as a pdf.

Please let me know if you might need extra clarification. Thank you for your time guys.

```py
    def send_by_email(self):
        for rec in self:
            filename = f"{(rec.name or '').replace('/','_')}_${rec.state}"
            pdf = self.env.ref(
                'hr_payroll_community.action_report_payslip').render_qweb_pdf(rec.id)
            _logger.info(base64.b64decode(pdf[0]))
            if pdf:
                #here i am testing to see if I can save the pdf but it's not working.

                pdf1 = pdf[0]
                pdf_path = rec.create_pdf()
                with open('/home/b14/Desktop/dd.pdf', 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(base64.decodebytes(pdf1))

                # add_encryption(pdf_path, pdf_path, '12345678')
                pdf_id = rec.save_pdf_file(pdf_path, filename)

                template_id = self.env.ref(
                    'send_payslips_by_email.email_template_send_payslip').id
                compose_form_id = self.env.ref(
                    'mail.email_compose_message_wizard_form').id
                ctx = dict(
                    default_model='hr.payslip',
                    default_res_id=self.id,
                    # IDK IF THIS FIELD BELOW ACTUALLY EXISTS
                    default_use_template=bool(template_id),
                    default_template_id=template_id,
                    # default_attachment_ids=[(0, 0, pdf_id)],
                    default_composition_mode='comment',
                )

                return {
                    'name': _('Compose Email'),
                    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                    'view_type': 'form',
                    'view_mode': 'form',
                    'res_model': 'mail.compose.message',
                    'views': [(compose_form_id, 'form')],
                    'view_id': compose_form_id,
                    'target': 'new',
                    'context': ctx,
                }
```

After this, there is the function to encrypt the pdf that I have confirmed it works well with other pdfs that are already saved on my machine.

```py
def add_encryption(input, output, password):
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(input)

    for page in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
        pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page))

    pdf_writer.encrypt(user_pwd=password, owner_pwd=None, use_128bit=True)

    with open('/home/b14/Desktop/pp.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        pdf_writer.write(f)
```

Comment: You have not asked any question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited the question. Thank you